# Conversion of dataframe into specially formatted list for use in function

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame like the following:

```
df = data.frame(name = c("chr", "test"), ncol = c(2, 3))
```

However, for input into a function (ComplexHeatmap), I need a list like the following:

```
list(chr = list(ncol = 2), test = list(ncol = 3))
```

What is the easiest way to convert from this data frame into a list of this format? Doing `as.list` does not get the right format.

Thanks!
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would involve using `plyr`. I suspect you may also have more than those two columns, so let

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("chr", "test"), ncol = c(2, 3), a = 1:2)
#   name ncol a
# 1  chr    2 1
# 2 test    3 2
```

Then

```
dlply(df, .(name), function(r) as.list(r[-1]))
# $chr
# $chr$ncol
# [1] 2
#
# $chr$a
# [1] 1
#
#
# $test
# $test$ncol
# [1] 3
#
# $test$a
# [1] 2
#
#
# attr(,"split_type")
# [1] "data.frame"
# attr(,"split_labels")
#   name
# 1  chr
# 2 test
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `split` from `base R`

```
split(setNames(as.list(df$ncol), rep('ncol', nrow(df))), df$name)
```